# PulseAudio: Can not create sink with specific name anymore

Tags: pulseaudio, scripts

Since having upgraded to Oneiric I can not create a sink in PulseAudio with a specific name. Usually I did it using this command:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=test
```

But now I get a sink with out the specified name. All sinks created are named »Null-Sink« and it does not seem to be possible to rename a sink.
Is this a bug in Pulse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To give another name for a newly created sink we may issue the following command

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=ANYNAME sink_properties=device.description="our_new_name"
```

This will also update the device.description field that contains the name of our newly created sink as it will be displayed in the sound preferences menu.

If you omit this the internal name of your sink is still `test` in your example as you will find out by running

```
pacmd list-sinks
```