# How to rename pulseaudio device?

Tags: pulseaudio

Is there any way of renaming pulseaudio server devices to something readable?

[image]

Comment: On creating any sink we can give it a custom name. See e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/85007/pulseaudio-can-not-create-sink-with-specific-name-anymore or http://askubuntu.com/questions/616155/sound-settings-window-too-wide - in case you need help on how to create a network sink from the command line just shout.